# Storybook error Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, storybook

I'm trying to get my Storybook working with my React app. I'm using redux 4.0.1.

I can't use a particular component where I also use redux. 
This is the error I'm getting:

> Storybook error Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

---

This is my my `devDependencies`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19"
  }
```

My component `Navbar.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props.auth;
    return (
      <div className="navbar-fixed">
        <nav className="z-depth-0">Hello, {user.name} </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Navbar);
```

And my story `2-Navbar.stories.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Provider from '../src/Provider.js'
import configureStore from "../src/configureStore";
import Navbar from '../src/components/layout/Navbar';

export default {
  title: 'Navbar',
  decorators: [storyFn => <Provider store={ configureStore }>{storyFn()}</Provider>]
};

export const Yay = () => <Navbar />;
```

I want to use "mock" data to pass to my navbar (Like name and avatar url) because otherwise I have redux errors.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrade StoryBook. The workaround that i found was delete node_modules folder, .storyBook folder, delete package-lock.json, and delete any reference to StoryBook in package.json. After that run "npx sb init" and "npm install". Then "npm run storybook" and the problem was fixed!